# 0/1 Knapsack algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am little bit confuse in this problem .As the algorithm help me finding the maximum profit from the bag .But this algorithm did not tell me that which item should i take that will make my maximum profit .As example
  n=4 items, capacity of knapsack M=8 ,profit=[15,10,9,5]  and weight is w=[1,5,3,4] respectively 
when i solve this i get the maximum profit of 29

here is the solution [http://www.mafy.lut.fi/study/DiscreteOpt/DYNKNAP.pdf]

but i want to know that which item should i take that will make the profit of 29.I don't want to make all the combination because if there are n items and have there N weight and profit respectively then how many combination will make .
So i want to know is there any solution for this or any other algorithm which can give me items whose total sum of profit is maximum.
Please help me .
waiting for reply!
thank you

Comment: http://www.darkeffort.com/blogs/blog/0_1_knapsack_problem_recursive_solution.html

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Programming:

> For 0/1 Knapsack you either take an entire item or leave it
>   completely. Hence, you have to calculate all possible solutions before
>   deciding which one is the best.

Greedy Approach

> In the other knapsack problem where you can take fractions of items,
>   you can go by cost, i.e. take the highest cost item and fill your
>   knapsack till either your knapsack is full or there is no more item,
>   then move on to the second most costly item and so on ...

Comment: OK i get it i have to calculate all possible solution and pick the best one but i will only work for small number of items like 4,5,6,7 but as i said earlier if i have N numbers of item hen how will i find absolute solution.because i do not want to sit and calculate off possible solution of N items

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/ This is the only way to solve 0/1 Knapsack.

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh it's a nice way for sure, but there are more ways, for example branch and bound using the linear relaxation (based on the greedy approach you quote but with a fractional item to fill up the last leftover capacity). Pro: accepts large capacity. Con: bad on subset sum instances.

Comment: @harold it is indeed a good way. but i dont think 0/1 knapsack lets you break down the item.

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh of course not, but you can use that as an upper bound, then you can reject partial solutions that you already know are definitely not optimal, thus pruning the search space (I suggested B&B as solution, not the linear relaxation itself)

Answer (score 0):

If your question still is "but i want to know that which item should i take", here's an implementation that prints actual items:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Knapsack
{

    private int counter = 0;
    private int[] values, weights;
    public Knapsack(int[] vs, int[] ws)
    {
        values = vs;
        weights = ws;
    }

    public Bag knap(int n, int w)
    {
        counter++;
        Bag ret = new Bag();
        if (n == -1) {
            return ret;
        }

        ret = knap(n - 1, w);
        assert ret.totalWeight() <= w;
        if (weights[n] > w) {
            // This weight alone is larger than our quota. Can't add any more.
            return ret;
        }
        int val1 = ret.totalValue();
        int weight1 = ret.totalWeight();
        int remain = w - weight1;
        if (weights[n] <= remain)
        {
            // We have space for this item. Add to bag.
            ret.add(n, values[n], weights[n]);
            return ret;
        }
        int max = w - weights[n];
        ArrayList<Integer> nitems2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Bag ret2 = knap(n - 1, w - weights[n]);
        ret2.add(n, values[n], weights[n]);
        int val2 = ret2.totalValue();
        int weight2 = ret2.totalWeight();
        if (val1 > val2) {
            return ret;
        } else {
            return ret2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] values = {15, 10, 9, 5};
        int[] weights = {1, 5, 3, 4};
        int M = 8;

        Knapsack ks = new Knapsack(values, weights);
        Bag ret = ks.knap(values.length - 1, M);
        System.out.println("Total value=" + ret.totalValue() + ", weight=" +
                       ret.totalWeight());
        List<Integer> items = ret.bagItems();
        System.out.print("Items: ");
        for (int i: items) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

class Bag {
    private int weight;
    private int value;
    private ArrayList<Integer> items;
    public Bag()
    {
        weight = 0;
        value = 0;
        items = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public void add(int itemno, int v, int w)
    {
        items.add(itemno);
        weight += w;
        value += v;
    }

    public int totalWeight() { return weight; }
    public int totalValue() { return value; }
    public List<Integer> bagItems() { return items; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

0-1 Knapsack does indeed want you weigh all the possible combinations because unlike in fractional knapsack, where we can use greedy algorithm to get max profit, the empty space lowers the effective profit per pound(weight) of the load. In 0-1 Knapsack, when we consider whether to include an item in the knapsack, we must compare the solution to the subproblem that includes the item with the solution to the subproblem that excludes the item before we can make a choice.

Hence the solution runs `O(nW)`, where n is the number of items and W is the weight of the items that you can put in the knapsack

Hope it clarifies!